# How to Find Tangent Line Without Tedious Derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, tangent-line

When I came across problem posted by Eyesima, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3569114/751970 , I realized that for functions which are symmetrical in $x$ and $y$, their tangent line at points $(a,a)$ can be found easily without tedious derivative, especially if the functions are complicated.

This led me to question if similar concept can be used for functions which are asymmetric in $x$ and $y$ and, it can, under some conditions of course.

For example, find the tangent line of the following curve at $(1,1)$.

$$
\tan^{-1}{\left(xy^{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{xy+y}}\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{\frac{3}{xy+xy^{2}+y}}=0
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the curve is asymmetric in $x$ and $y$, it is symmetric in $xy$ and $y$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\tan^{-1}{\left(xy^{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{xy+y}}\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{\frac{3}{xy+xy^{2}+y}}&=0\\
\tan^{-1}{\left(xy\cdot y\sqrt{\frac{2}{xy+y}}\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{\frac{3}{xy+xy\cdot y+y}}&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Furthermore, at $(1,1)$, $xy=y$. Therefore, at $(1,1)$ the following equation applies

$$
\begin{aligned}
d(xy)+dy&=0\\
x\ dy + y\ dx + dy&=0\\
dy+dx+dy&=0\\
2dy+dx&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

and the tangent line is $2y+x-3=0$.

This is only one example.